# Why can't I acces my Mac's webserver from my iPhone using the Mac's ad-hoc WiFi?

Tags: wifi, ad-hoc

I want to do a demo of an iPhone optimised WebApp using my MacBook Air with a local server, so I don't have to depend on getting an internet connection or WiFi access from my client.

The Air is running Lion 10.7.2 and the iPhone is on iOS 5.0.1.

When I create a network on the Mac I can join from the iPhone, but when I open "http://my-macbook-air/" in Safari, it doesn't work.

Strangely it doesn't seem to utilize the WiFi, as the indicator never appears (but shows connected in the Settings app).

Possibly related:
[Why is my iPhone unable to connect to an ad hoc wifi network?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/why-is-my-iphone-unable-to-connect-to-an-ad-hoc-wifi-network) (though my question is Apple <-> Apple, so I expected it to work).

Comment: If the Wi-Fi indicator on the iPhone doesn't come it, it's probably not (fully) connected. How do you create the network on the Mac?

Comment: I create it using "Create Network" from the WiFi indicator.

Comment: I don't get the WiFi connector either that way but can access the web server on the Mac with the IP address of the ad-hoc network. See below for a screenshot.

Comment: Are you using the built in 'Web Sharing' feature of OS X? If not, what are you using?

Comment: The URL should be `http://my-macbook-air.local`. As Jason points out you need to use 'Web Sharing' and be on the same LAN.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably related to resolving the host name.

Try using the IP address of the Mac instead of the name:

[image]

Comment: Using the Mac's IP didn't help (obtained from ifconfig). I assume Safari/iOS is not using the WiFi because it offers no internet connection?

Comment: Did you pick the right one? In my case it's `en1` in ifconfig, you can also get it from Preferences/Network (see screenshot).

Comment: Nope, using that IP (which is the same ifconfig gave me), doesn't work either. Tried the built-in apache and my dev server both to no avail.

Comment: This is really frustrating. I tried doing it the other way around, using the Mobile Hotspot, but then I get an indicator bar at the top that will stay there all the time, so whether or not they could connect that way, it's not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps here: http://egalo.com/2012/05/29/testing-mac-web-site-using-local-hostname-on-mobile-device/

It took about 5 minutes to setup and works really well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the firewall rules apply to an ad-hoc network, but I spent days with both the apache server and python's SimpleHTTPServer without being able to connect my iphone up, although i was able to connect the iPhone to a windows box running SimpleHTTPServer.  It ended up simply being the MAC OS firewall.  Turn it off in System Preference -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall.  It blocks incoming connections.